# Protecting data on rented servers

Tags: mysql, security, server-side

How can I protect my data stored in a database on a rented server(dedicated, shared, cloud).  Anyone who works for the host company can clone a disk from my computer and steal my data.

If I encrypt the database I will lose performance.  One other option I'm considering is to run mysql database out of ram only and encrypt database backups.

Is there any other ways to protect my data on a rented server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you encrypt your database the hose can still access it. You'll need to store the key somewhere within your site/app so that you have access to the data. The host can then potentially use that key to access the data.

I'm not seeing how running the database in memory helps at all with this. You still need to access the data and the host could do a db dump from the database whether it's running from the drive or from memory.

One option might be to use your own hardware in a co-location type setup where you are the only one who has physical access to your box. There are a lot of disadvantages to this method but if you are serious about wanting to really lock down your data, I think is pretty much your only solution.

That said, is your data valuable enough to warrant someone from one of the major hosting providers snooping through your stuff?

Comment: if mysql is running out of ram they can't clone my disk and get the info.  In order to do a dump from ram they would have to log into mysql first.

Comment: Wouldn't logging into MySQL be trivial if they have physical access to the server? Somewhere on the server is the database info which you need to know that it's running in memory, what the db name is, etc. Your login info HAS to be stored somewhere so your site/app can connect to it. Once you have that, it doesn't matter where it is, it can be dumped very quickly.

Comment: I was going to store the mysql credentials in a file on ram too.  The only way to get at this info is to log in to the computer.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't trust them, you shouldn't be renting a server from them. No matter what you do, the host can potentially reverse-engineer it. After all, if your code to encrypt data before putting it in their database is also on their servers, nothing is stopping them from using it to retrieve the information.

If your trust issues go beyond the realms of what is normal, your only real option is to buy a server and a high-end upstream network connection... and then trust your ISP not to sniff it.